# Access controller in extjs kitchensink menu example

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I have an ExtJs 6.2. application (modern toolkit) and I want to implement the [menu example](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#menus) (the top menu). Therefore I have this code in my `Main.js` file:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'app-main',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'center',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    controller: 'mainController',
    margin: '0 0 0 0',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        style: 'background-color: red;',
        items: [{
            text: 'Menu',
            handler: function() {
                Ext.Viewport.toggleMenu('top');
            }
        }]
    }],
    initialize: function() {
         Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.getMenuCfg('top'), {side: 'top' });
    },

    doDestroy: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.removeMenu('top');
        this.callParent();
    },
    getMenuCfg: function(side) {
        return {
            items: [{
                text: 'Foo',
                handler: 'onFooClick',
                controller: 'mainController'
            }]
        };
    }
});
```

When I click on the `Menu` the menu shows up (as I want it). But when I click on the `foo` button inside the menu I get this error:

```
No method named "onFooClick" on Ext.Button(...)
```

My controller `MainController.js` in the same directory looks as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.mainController',


    onFooClick: function() {
        console.log("foo pressed");
    }
});
```

I already tried to set a `scope` like this (in the `getMenuCfg` function):

```
 items: [{
                    text: 'Foo',
                    handler: 'onFooClick',
                    controller: 'mainController',
                    scope: 'controller'
                }]
```

But then I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Named method "onFooClick" requires a scope object(…)
```

How can I access my Controller using this menu?

Comment: Please check all occurences of `onCreateFolderClick`, `onFooClick`, `onFooClicked` whether you use the same name, so we can be sure that the issue isn't a wrongly named function or call.

Comment: I mixed up the names of the method while creating a minimal example for stackoverflow but I got it right in my application (just checked it to be sure). Is there something else that may cause a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out what the problem is but created a workaround by adding this `onfooClick` function to the `Main.js` file:

```
onfooClick: function () {
        this.getController(Ext.String.capitalize('mainController')).onFooClick();
}
```

This will call the own `onFooClick` method inside `Main.js` which calls the `onFooClick`method from the controller.